# Error: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters

Tags: java, http, url

I am trying to send a string from one application to another. I would be returning a response which is a string.  Here, myhost.com/views is the 2nd application where I need to send the string value and get a response from it. But when I am trying to send it is not executing this code. Can someone please correct me where I am wrong?

Below is the code I have written.

```
  public static void sendData(String strval) throws IOException{ 
String doSend="https://myhost.com/views?strval="+strval;
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     try {
         System.out.println("inside try");
         URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
         System.out.println("builder="+builder);

         builder.setHost("myhost.com").setPath("/views");
         builder.addParameter("strval", strval); 
         System.out.println("add param,sethost,setpath complete");

         URI uri = builder.build();
         System.out.println("uri="+uri);


         HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri); 
         System.out.println("httpGet"+httpget);

         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
         System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

         if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println("responseText="+responseText);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
         } else {
           System.out.println("Server returned HTTP code "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
         }
      } catch (java.net.URISyntaxException bad) {
         System.out.println("URI construction error: " + bad.toString());
      }
      catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("e.getMessage=>"+e.getMessage());  }

    }
```

Code runs till and when I print the exceptions I see excep.getMessage() ->

```
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:789)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
```

Comment: Can you find the list of jars on the classpath? You need both the httpclient jar and httpcore jars.

Comment: Problem was with the version of httpcore jar that I was using.
version 4.2.1 is incompatible, I used version 4.2.3 and it worked fine until 

   HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);  Updated the exception stack as I am seeing other errors in the same code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code is not able to recognize it as a valid `URI` since it was missing `http`. This is what I added to resolve the code:

```
builder.setScheme("http");
```